# Heroku pulls a duplicate column error in a rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

After pushing my master branch to heroku from git, I'm now trying to migrate my db file to heroku also but I came across this error

```
clydiscope$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6472
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20141203201816)
== 20141203201816 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.3488s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0146s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0143s
== 20141203201816 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.3782s) =======================

Migrating to AddNameToUsers (20141206140057)
== 20141206140057 AddNameToUsers: migrating ===================================
-- add_column(:users, :name, :string)
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "name" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "name" character varying(255)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "name" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "name" character 

/app/db/migrate/20141206140057_add_name_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
```

Apparently, there's a duplicate column that I wasn't aware of... 
I was continuously migrating in the development phase and it seemed to work up to this point. How can I change ,my db now so that heroku accepts it?

Here's the code from the last line.

```
 class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
    add_column :users, :name, :string
 end

def down
  remove_column :users, :name
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably just deleting the migration file `20141206140057_add_name_to_users.rb` will solve the problem (of course, after committing and push to Heroku).

Comment: I thought about that, but I guess I was afraid of negatively altering something. Do I `rake db:migrate` this change before I commit?

Comment: That depends on your previous and next migrations, you need to make some local tests before deploying to Heroku.

Comment: great, I simply just removed the file and everything seemed to work ok, thanks!